# Null reference on Entity Framework Migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration

When I user the Add-Migration command of Entity Framework migration I get the following exception:

> `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.GetFileName(Project project, String projectItemName)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsCommands..ctor(Object project, Object startUpProject, String configurationTypeName, String connectionStringName, String connectionString, String connectionProviderName, PSCmdlet cmdlet)`

Any insight?

Comment: What was the full command line? Did you point it to an existing file? Was the file actually there?

Comment: Could you post some more details? Have you already activated Migrations for your project (the initial file)? What changes have you made?

Comment: The command was like "Add-Migration Migration05". Migration was working fine. I moved the project to TFS and now it won't work anymore. I'm using EF 4.3

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I've seen this before when there are multiple projects in the solution and the "wrong" project is selected as the startup project. For example, somebody else reported that in an Azure hosted MVC3 website they had the Azure project as the startup project instead of the MVC project. Switching over to the MVC project as the startup fixed the issue.

**Update:** This has been fixed in EF5-beta2, which is now available on NuGet.

Comment: I confirm Arthurs solution. Also that the correct project be selected in Package Manager Console.

Comment: thanks...  setting the startup project to mvc instead of azure worked for me.

Comment: Happened to me when I had 2 VS2012 open with different projects. Closing the other one solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually very easily specify the target project in your Package Manager Console when calling any EF command by just using the correct flags and arguments, for instance, given a project called ProjectFoo out of a solution with multiple projects:

- `enable-migrations -projectname projectfoo`
- `add-migration "Initial" -projectname projectfoo`
- `update-database -projectname projectfoo`
  etc...

Easy as pie.