# Code First Entity Framework and Windows Azure SQL

Tags: entity-framework, azure, ef-code-first, code-first, azure-sql-database

I am trying move a very simple code first example from my local SQL on to Azure SQL and as it appears I've hit a brick wall.

This is the simple code that I am using:

```
public class Cat
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

**Context class:**

public class CatDbContext : DbContext
{
    public PersonDbContext()
        : base("name=MyConnectionString")
    { }
    public DbSet<Cat> Cats { get; set; }
}

My connection string:
 <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Server=tcp:xxxx.database.windows.net;Database=xxxx;User ID=xxxx@xxxx;Password=xxxx;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Now I have a simple console app which does the following:

```
        CatDbContext db = new CatDbContext();
        db.Cats.Add(new Cat { Name = "Garfield", ID = Guid.NewGuid() });
        db.SaveChanges();
```

And I am getting an exception at line db.SaveChanges(); saying:
Invalid object name 'dbo.Cats'.

Stack trace:

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
```

And no tables are created.
I will be very thankful if someone could point me in the right direction, as I have no clue why this is happening.

Kind regards,
Audrius.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done this today using EF Code First Migrations. It will create your tables initially and also enable DB upgrades in the future. Refer to this [walkthrough](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/web-site-with-sql-database/) for more information. I think this is the recommended approach. Should you get a NullReferenceException in the package manager, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481784/null-reference-on-entity-framework-migration).

[Another hint](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adonetefx/thread/1e828c99-66a9-4094-87ec-e799bd619463/) (scroll all the way down) is that your connection string has to target the SQL Azure master db, but this information may be outdated and I didn't try it.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems Entity Framework does not create Azure SQL tables for you in a code first appraoch, therefore you have to use a model first approach, generate the SQL script for the data model, and run the script over the web-based sql manager available in Azure.

Also suggest replacing

```
[id] uniqueidentifier not null,
```

With

```
[id] uniqueidentifier not null default newid(),
```

for every primary key, as database generated keys do not work otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

CodeFirst works well with SQL Azure.

This used to be an issue with EF 4.1 (-) Please make sure you are using the most recent version of EF (4.3.1 as by today at NuGet). Also make sure that the user you are specifying in the connection string has enough permissions to create database objects in the target database.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `PersistSecurityInfo=true` in your connection string will give your local machine permission to create the database in Azure. Make sure to remove it after creating the database.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and setting up a DB Initializer was the solution that finally created the tables.
Just put the following in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyContext>());
```