# Seed method unable to add foreign key object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am creating a database with football teams that have players. I am using the seed method to add my data but Entity framework won't update my database throwing the **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.** error.

I am unsure how to link the relations in the seed method. Down below is the code.

---

Seed Method

```
protected override void Seed(DataLayer.FootballContext context)
 {
        List<VoetbalPloeg> VoetbalPloegModels = new List<VoetbalPloeg>();

        VoetbalPloegModels.Add(new VoetbalPloeg()
        {
            PloegNaam = "FC Barcelona",
            StamNummer = 1241,
            Spelers =
            {
                new Speler() { VoorNaam = "Lionel", AchterNaam = "Messi", Assists = 2, Goals = 15, GeboorteDatum = new DateTime(1990, 05, 15), Positie = "Spits", Rugnummer = 10},
                new Speler() { VoorNaam = "Alonso", AchterNaam = "Xabi", Assists = 3, Goals = 7, GeboorteDatum = new DateTime(1985, 04, 24), Positie = "Centraal", Rugnummer = 13}
            }
        });

        VoetbalPloegModels.Add(new VoetbalPloeg()
        {
            PloegNaam = "Real Madrid",
            StamNummer = 1546,
            Spelers =
            {
                new Speler() { VoorNaam = "Cristano", AchterNaam = "Ronaldo", Assists = 0, Goals = 17, GeboorteDatum = new DateTime(1989, 10, 7), Positie = "Spits", Rugnummer = 7},
                new Speler() { VoorNaam = "Sergio", AchterNaam = "Ramos", Assists = 0, Goals = 4, GeboorteDatum = new DateTime(1986, 12, 04), Positie = "LaatsteMan", Rugnummer = 10}
            }
        });

        foreach (var item in VoetbalPloegModels)
            context.VoetbalPloeg.Add(item);

        base.Seed(context);
 }
```

Player Model

```
public class Speler
{
    [Key]
    public int SpelerId { get; set; }
    public string VoorNaam { get; set; }
    public string AchterNaam { get; set; }
    public int Rugnummer { get; set; }
    public string Positie { get; set; }
    public int Goals { get; set; }
    public int Assists { get; set; }
    public DateTime GeboorteDatum { get; set; }

    // Forgein Key
   // public int VoetbalPloegId { get; set; }

    // Navigation Property
   //public virtual VoetbalPloeg VoetbalPloeg { get; set; }

}
```

Football Team Model

```
public class VoetbalPloeg
{
    [Key]
    public int VoetbalPloegId { get; set; }
    public string PloegNaam { get; set; }
    public int StamNummer { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Speler> Spelers { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT: the question marked as answer is the first result you get in google when you type in my general error message.

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: none I use update-database in the pm console

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Null reference on Entity Framework Migration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481784/null-reference-on-entity-framework-migration)

Comment: Well, your question is really misleading for any one reading it, there's nothing related to the foreign key and the error you stated...

Comment: @gusman You don't seem to understand my code very well. This works fine without the relations being linked in the seed method but when I want to link the players with my teams it all goes wrong. note: I said **foreign key object** referring to the fact that you need to input your object to link your database. So could you not pick a random question on stackoverflow so you can mark it as duplicate. thank you :)

Comment: You stated: *Which line is throwing the exception? none I use update-database in the pm console* so your code should not make a difference, or it would give you the stack trace, I did not added a random answer, that answer os for the exact same error at the exact same moment executing the exact same command on pm...

Comment: The guy on the link you posted picked the wrong project folder. Doesn't seem to be linked to my issue.

Comment: Run your code in debug mode without a database so it is created while running. Then see where the exception occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running seed from your `Configuration.cs` in Migrations folder use:

```
 public Configuration()
 {
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
 }

 protected override void Seed(TestContext context)
    {
        // Where 'VoetbalPloegs' is the name of your table in the dbcontext

        context.Spelers.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Id,
            new Speler() { Id = 1, VoorNaam = "Lionel", AchterNaam = "Messi", Assists = 2, Goals = 15, GeboorteDatum = new DateTime(1990, 05, 15), Positie = "Spits", Rugnummer = 10, VoetbalPloegId = 1 },
            new Speler() { Id = 2, VoorNaam = "Alonso", AchterNaam = "Xabi", Assists = 3, Goals = 7, GeboorteDatum = new DateTime(1985, 04, 24), Positie = "Centraal", Rugnummer = 13, VoetbalPloegId = 1},
            new Speler() { Id = 3, VoorNaam = "Cristano", AchterNaam = "Ronaldo", Assists = 0, Goals = 17, GeboorteDatum = new DateTime(1989, 10, 7), Positie = "Spits", Rugnummer = 7, VoetbalPloegId = 2 },
            new Speler() { Id = 4, VoorNaam = "Sergio", AchterNaam = "Ramos", Assists = 0, Goals = 4, GeboorteDatum = new DateTime(1986, 12, 04), Positie = "LaatsteMan", Rugnummer = 10, VoetbalPloegId = 2}
            );

        context.VoetbalPloegs.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Id,
            new VoetbalPloeg() { Id = 1, PloegNaam = "FC Barcelona", StamNummer = 1241 },
            new VoetbalPloeg() { Id = 2, PloegNaam = "Real Madrid", StamNummer = 1546 }
           );
    }
```

Make sure Automatic migrations set to true (as above).

Speler Entity:

```
 public class Speler
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string VoorNaam { get; set; }
    public string AchterNaam { get; set; }
    public int Rugnummer { get; set; }
    public string Positie { get; set; }
    public int Goals { get; set; }
    public int Assists { get; set; }
    public DateTime GeboorteDatum { get; set; }

    // Forgein Key
    public int VoetbalPloegId { get; set; }
}
```

VoetbalPloeg Entity:

```
public class VoetbalPloeg
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PloegNaam { get; set; }
    public int StamNummer { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Speler> Spelers { get; set; }
}
```

In DbContext Add:

```
public DbSet<Speler> Spelers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<VoetbalPloeg> VoetbalPloegs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<VoetbalPloeg>().HasMany(s => s.Spelers).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(h => h.VoetbalPloegId);

    }
```

Comment: Still get the error message maybe the issue lies with how I link my relation in my model?

Comment: works but now I don't have link between the players and the team

Comment: @Mercenary_Frank Add a new navigation property   public virtual VoetbalPloeg VoetbalPloeg {get; set;} into class Speler.